# Three.js Skinning Animation (r74+) Functionality

Tags: three.js, skinning

With the old three.js (r72-) animation system it was possible to begin an animation at a specified time.

I did something along the lines of:

```
// anim being an instance of THREE.Animation

var duration = anim.data.length;

anim.currentTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.floor(duration) - 0 + 1)) + 0;

anim.play();
```

I have been less than successful in achieving this with the new animation system. Does anyone happen to know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. You need to update the mixer with the desired start time, not update the clip time directly. So:

```
// mixer being an instance of THREE.AnimationMixer
// clip being an instance of THREE.AnimationClip

var duration = clip.duration;

var start = (Math.random() * (duration - 0) + 0).toFixed(4);

clip.play();

mixer.update(start);
```

I have found that you must play the clip first before calling `mixer.update(start);`.